# How to choose the type based on the run-time needs?

Tags: c, int

I have the following situation and I'm expecting some expert advise from SO folks.

I'm writing an application and as a part of that I need to expose an `API` for creation, modification and deletion of object(s). Each object that gets created should be uniquely identified (only with positive identifiers)!

The system will have the following number of objects in a given day.

1. Minimal - `<50,000 objects` (`60%` - `14.4/24 hrs`)
2. Average - `>50,ooo but <65,000 objects` (`30%` - `7.2/24 hrs`)
3. Peak - `>65,000 but <100,000 objects` (`10%` - `2.4/24 hrs`)

Now, the question is, what should be the `type` of the object identifier? The case `#1` and `#2` will fit within `unsigned short int` (`2 bytes`). But it cannot accommodate the objects for case `#3`. So case `#3` needs a wider type like `int` (`4 bytes`).

I don't want to use an `int` when the system is in case `#1` and case `#2` (`90%` of time), because, say there are currently `65k` objects in the system and if we use `int` to hold object-id then we will use double the size of memory compare to using `unsigned short int`. OTOH, when the system is in peak (`10%` of time) we definitely need `int` to store the object-id.

And, there could be time when the system fluctuates between case `#2` and `#3` based on the users needs.

In `C`, is there a way to handle this situation in a memory efficient way i.e. by changing the `type` of the object-id based on the usage at run-time?!

NOTE: when objects get deleted, the deleted object-id will used for the creation of next object. And object-id wrapping will be done only in the corner case (until and unless it is absolutely required).

Comment: "we will use double the size of memory" <-- no, you seem to forget about alignment.

Comment: With 100,000 objects, changing one `short` to an `int` in each of them (assuming `int` is 4 bytes) will cause your program to consume 200 kilobytes more memory than if you used a short (assuming `short` is 2 bytes), and also assuming the compiler didn't pad the extra two bytes with filler (in which case `int` would take up the same amount of space as `short`). Are you sure you can't afford that?

Comment: You are correct. There will be alignment issues to.. So `double` may not be the right word. How about - we will need considerably more memory when using `int` compare to using `unsigned short int`

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj no, he's saying you probably won't need any more because the compiler will probably pad the extra two bytes anyway.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie:  You mean 200 kilobytes?

Comment: Using integers which size less than native int will not save your memory until that values stored in an array (because of alignment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C language doesn't support changing the type of something dynamically.  You could probably figure out how to do it one way or another, but it could involve compiling most of your code twice (once for the 16-bit ints and once for the 32-bit ints) and then choosing at run time which version of the code to run.  This sounds like a massive pain, and it will only save you 200 kB of memory at most (if anything).

Your computer probably has gigabytes of memory already so I can't imagine 200 kB will make a difference.  If you're actually working on an ancient machine with 16 MB of memory then ask your boss for a better machine.  Programmers are expensive and hardware is cheap.

Comment: +1 for `Programmers are expensive and hardware is cheap`. But unfortunately having more memory is not a option in this case. I need to try and work this out in the code.

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj how much memory does the machine you are using have?

Answer (score 1):

If memory usage is critical for you, you can use complex id that will consist of unsigned short and unsigned char - you`ll get 24-bit id and it will be enough for 2^24 = 16777216 objects. Of course it will have some impact on performance, but in such way you can get rid of reallocating space for identifiers.

In case if it is premature optimization - just don`t do it.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a case of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), you're trying to optimize your memory foot print before you even know if it will become an issue for the production server you're running on.

As stated above there are many issues to do with padding and alignment that means that any saving you envisage could ultimately be rendered mute by the compiler. At the same time you're making your code harder to understand and debug with the proposed optimisation of changing the type of the object ID at runtime.

In other words, code it using the smallest type that fits the problem then optimize if it proves that the memory usage is too much. Even if you do get some errors because it is using too much memory, memory is cheap, buy more.

Comment: You mean "the _smallest_ type that fits the problem"?

Answer (score 0):

If memory efficiency matter, take a look at trick that [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) use.

Answer (score 0):

This may be analogous to the implementation of `pid_t` type for process-id in `Linux`. the `Linux` user is given an option to increase the maximum number of process/threads created by modifying `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` file. Another idea is to try and create `opaque types` as mentioned [here](http://c-faq.com/struct/opaque.examp.html).